# How to exclude jar from gradle idea plugin

Tags: java, gradle, plugins

I'm working on an Idea plugin and currently stuck on sandbox starting issue:

```
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/kamil/projects/tx/build/idea-sandbox/plugins/modif-tx/lib/tx-slf4j-2018.1.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/kamil/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/ideaIC/2018.1/d082978a55b398ef544e7daee1dd6228b88dbfc1/ideaIC-2018.1/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
```

Compilation works fine though.
I'd like to exclude `slf4j` jar from idea plugin. How can I achieve that with gradle?

Comment: Any luck with this? I am facing the same issue.